# R - data.frame subsetting with substring searching

Tags: r, string, text, dataframe, subset

From a given data.frame with a text column I need to subset row which contain character substring previously stored in a vector (or in a second data.frame column).

```
Example data:

require(stringi) # Used for generate random string
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1), stri_rand_strings(10, 5)))

df

  V1    V2
1   1 GNZuC
2   2 twed3
3   3 CAgNl
4   4 UizNm
5   5 vDe7G
6   6 N0NrL
7   7 TbUBp
8   8 fn6iP
9   9 oemYW
10 10 m1Tjg
```

If I store the searched substrings in a vector as showed

```
tofind <- c("AgN", "bUB")
```

As result I need to obtain the following data.frame

```
  V1    V2
1   3 CAgNl
2   7 TbUBp
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works if you change your `tofind` vector (with capital N):

```
tofind <- c("AgN", "bUB")

df[grep(paste(tofind, collapse = "|"), df$V2),]

  V1    V2
3  3 CAgNl
7  7 TbUBp
```

And using `subset` function:

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(tofind, collapse = "|"), V2))
```

Here you use `grepl` instead of `grep` because `subset` function requires a logical vector not numeric

Comment: It work fine also on real large data-set. My impasse is solved. One extension to the question: is it possible to have an equivalent solution using the subset statement ?

Comment: Although verbose find more easy to use the subset syntax.
I've fixed my error for further readers. Thanks of all.